# Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_captureデータの連続取得とSPI経由でのデータ通信について

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_captureではバッファにデータがたまると終了するようになっていますが、これを

データ収録開始→バッファにデータが貯まる→データ取り出し&データをSPI送信→バッファクリア→データ収録開始→…

のようなサイクルにしたいのですが、連続して音声データをキャプチャする場合、

theAudio->startRecorder();
↓
theAudio->readFrames(...);
↓
theAudio->stopRecorder();
↓
theAudio->startRecorder();
↓
…
のように繰り返すことになるのでしょうか？
可能であればサンプルコードをご提示願えませんでしょうか

もうひとつ、SpresenseにおいてSPI通信を行う場合、Spresenseをスレーブとして動作させることは可能でしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ford shelling さん

pcm_captureのスケッチにある、
theAudio->readFrames(s_buffer, buffer_size, size);
は、readFramesを呼ぶことで、theAudioの中のFIFOからデータを読み出して、
FIFOのread pointerを進めていくようです。

なので、リアルタイムで読み出し続けるようなアプリケーションの場合、
theAudio->readFrames
を呼び続けるだけで、start/stopは不要だと思われます。

また、SpresenseのSPIはmaster機能しかないように見えますね。